# async/await and promise.all in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, concurrency

I do have a question about async/await and promise.all in node.js:

I write a bot that checks prices on decentralised exchanges like quickswap, sushiswap and uniswap.
Therefore I do have a js file where the routes to check are included. It looks like this:

```
const routes = [
  [
    //1.1
    "quick / sushi - 2x2",
    token_Address_wmatic,
    token_Address_usdc,
    token_Address_weth,
    token_Address_usdt,
    token_Address_wmatic,
    "WMATIC - USDC - WETH - USDT - WMATIC",
  ],
  [
    //1.2
    "sushi / quick - 2x2",
    token_Address_wmatic,
    token_Address_usdt,
    token_Address_weth,
    token_Address_usdc,
    token_Address_wmatic,
    "WMATIC - USDT - WETH - USDC - WMATIC",
  ],
  [
    //2.1
    "quick / sushi - 1x1",
    token_Address_wmatic,
    token_Address_weth,
    token_Address_wmatic,
    "-",
    "-",
    "WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC",
  ],
  [
    //2.2
    "sushi / quick - 1x1",
    token_Address_wmatic,
    token_Address_weth,
    token_Address_wmatic,
    "-",
    "-",
    "WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC",
   ],  
 ];
    
 module.exports = routes;
```

I am using this routes in my main node.js file:

```
async function calc(route, amount_wei) {
  try {
    switch (route[0]) {
      case "quick / sushi - 2x2":
        amountOut = await quotes_5(
          quickswap_router,
          sushiswap_router,
          route,
          amount_wei
        );
        break;
      case "sushi / quick - 2x2":
        amountOut = await quotes_5(
          sushiswap_router,
          quickswap_router,
          route,
          amount_wei
        );
        break;
      case "quick / sushi - 1x1":
        amountOut = await quotes_2(
          quickswap_router,
          sushiswap_router,
          route,
          amount_wei
        );
        break;

      case "sushi / quick - 1x1":
        amountOut = await quotes_2(
          sushiswap_router,
          quickswap_router,
          route,
          amount_wei
        );
        break;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    var amountOut = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  }
  return amountOut;
   }
```

I am calling the calc function like this:

```
const result_routes = await Promise.all(
    routes.map(async (route) => calc(route, amount_start))
  );

console.log(result_routes);
```

But for some routes, there are exact the same results. What should be incorrect. I expect every route to get different results. You can see in results array are way different values than in the sequential example below.
Results:

```
{
    route: [
      'quick / sushi - 1x1',
      '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
      '0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619',
      '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
      '-',
      '-',
      'WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC'
    ],
    result: [
      '10000000000',
      '9099197560',
      '9558303845057372114568',
      0,
      0,
      9558.3
    ]
  },
  {
    route: [
      'sushi / quick - 1x1',
      '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
      '0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619',
      '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
      '-',
      '-',
      'WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC'
    ],
    result: [
      '10000000000',
      '9099197560',
      '9558303845057372114568',
      0,
      0,
      9558.3
    ]
  },
```

And if I fetch the routes like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
  erg = await calc(routes[i], amount_start);
  console.log(erg);
}
```

I get different results for each route.
Results:

```
route: [
    'quick / sushi - 1x1',
    '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
    '0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619',
    '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
    '-',
    '-',
    'WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC'
   ],
   result: [
    '10000000000000000000000',
    '7458279716470527164',
    '9858081993246032795263',
    0,
      0,
      9858.08
     ]
    },
    {
   route: [
    'sushi / quick - 1x1',
    '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
    '0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619',
    '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
    '-',
    '-',
    'WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC'
   ],
   result: [
    '10000000000000000000000',
    '7456852002788490479',
    '9860515589493070726861',
    0,
    0,
    9860.52
   ]
}
```

Is there a problem with my first way to do it? Because I want to fetch the routes concurrently, but I think I missundestand something. Can someone help me with this issue?

Thank you!

I expect my code to fetch all routes concurrently but also seperately. At the moment it seemes, that some calculations got overwright during the calculation process.

---

Added at 22. Nov 2022:
I tried the following:

```
const result_routes = await Promise.all(
        routes.map(async (route) => {
          return await calc(route, amount_start);
        })
      ).then((result_routes) => {
        result_routes.forEach(function (res) {
          console.log(res.route[0], ": ", res.route[6], ": ", res.result[5]);
        });
      });
```

The Output for example is:

```
quick / sushi - 2x2 :  WMATIC - USDC - WETH - USDT - WMATIC :  9066.37
sushi / quick - 2x2 :  WMATIC - USDT - WETH - USDC - WMATIC :  9066.37
quick / sushi - 1x1 :  WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC :  9369.05
sushi / quick - 1x1 :  WMATIC - WETH - WMATIC :  9369.05
quick / sushi - 2x1 :  WMATIC - DAI - USDC - WMATIC :  5427.25
sushi / quick - 1x2 :  WMATIC - USDC - DAI - WMATIC :  5440.61
quick / sushi - 2x2 :  WMATIC - USDC - DAI - USDC - WMATIC :  9066.37
sushi / quick - 2x2 :  WMATIC - USDC - DAI - USDC - WMATIC :  9066.37
quick / sushi - 2x2 :  WMATIC - USDC - TUSD - USDC - WMATIC :  9066.37
sushi / quick - 2x2 :  WMATIC - USDC - TUSD - USDC - WMATIC :  9066.37
quick / sushi - 1x1 :  WMATIC - USDC - WMATIC :  9369.05
sushi / quick - 1x1 :  WMATIC - USDC - WMATIC :  9369.05
quick / sushi - 1x1 :  USDC - DAI - USDC :  9369.05
sushi / quick - 1x1 :  USDC - DAI - USDC :  9369.05
quick / sushi - 1x1 :  USDC - WETH - USDC :  9369.05
sushi / quick - 1x1 :  USDC - WETH - USDC :  9369.05
quick / sushi - 1x1 :  USDC - TUSD - USDC :  9369.05
sushi / quick - 1x1 :  USDC - TUSD - USDC :  9369.05
quick / sushi - 2x2 :  USDC - WETH - WMATIC - WETH - USDC :  9066.37
sushi / quick - 2x2 :  USDC - WETH - WMATIC - WETH - USDC :  9066.37
quick / sushi - 2x2 :  USDC - QUICK - WMATIC - SUSHI - USDC :  9066.37
sushi / quick - 2x2 :  USDC - SUSHI - WMATIC - QUICK - USDC :  9066.37
```

So a lot of routes are giving the exact same output, which in my opinion has to be wrong.
Can someone tell me where I am doing the mistake?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if the way you call the calc function is right - it's not a function, so the value of route is undefined, which will use the first route every time. Basically you missed the squiggly brackets.

Should it not look like this?:

```js
const result_routes = await Promise.all(
    routes.map(async (route) => {calc(route, amount_start)})
  );

console.log(result_routes);
```

THEN the value of route will be passed to calc properly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that does not work, i only got undefined as a result then.

Comment: If you're getting undefined then thats actually progress - you're getting the undefined becuase the console.log() is occuring before the calls to calc() happen. I know you have `await Promise...` but I think there's still some synchronous/async silliness going on. But you definately need those squiggly brackets. Try {await calc(route, amount)}) and see if that helps...

Else re-write the section to use .then, and put console.log in a .then after the Promise

Comment: Hate comments here, all go inline and make code hard to read! I guess I should actually edit my answer, but I don't want to do that until you can confirm it worked. You could try `await Promise.all(...).then((result_routes) => {console.log(result_routes)});`

Comment: Oh, and you're not returning a value from the lambda function, something like `=> {return calc(route, amount_start)})`

Comment: I do have the same problem after trying all suggestions (I get the same output for a few routes.

Comment: Hello @Noscere, I tried it for a long time now, but I still think there has to be an error. I used it the way you told me (I hope I did it the right way), but I still think something has to be wrong, because so many routes giving the exact same output. Can you maybe have a look again? I am very grateful for your help

Comment: Sorry @Dani I've been away - did you make any progress on this, or do you still need another look at it>?

Comment: Sorry, i've been away too. And I didnt solve it yet. I tried a few times, but it seems like something going wrong every time.